# How to Create a UserControl using MVVM in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin, mvvm, xamarin.forms

I have tried to develop a usercontrol in Xamarin.Forms but I am not able to bind the controls of that Usercontrol using ViewModel.

My CustomeEntryUserControl is look like

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Grid xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" x:Class="LearningApp.UserControls.CustomeEntry"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:LearningApp.Extension">

    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="20" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Entry Grid.Column="0"  x:Name="entry" />
    <local:RoundedButton Grid.Column="1" Text="X" BackgroundColor="Gray" TextColor="White" HeightRequest="20" WidthRequest="10" VerticalOptions="Center" Margin="-30,0,30,0" x:Name="cancelbtn" />

</Grid>
```

Code behind of this usercontrol is look like

```
 public partial class CustomeEntry : Grid
{
    public CustomeEntry()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }

    public static readonly BindableProperty TextProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(Text), typeof(string), typeof(CustomeEntry), default(string));

    public static readonly BindableProperty CommandProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(Command), typeof(CustomeEntry), typeof(ICommand), default(ICommand));

    public ICommand Command
    {
        get { return (ICommand)GetValue(CommandProperty); }
        set { SetValue(CommandProperty, value); }
    }
    public string Text
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(TextProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TextProperty, value); }
    }

    public string PlaceHolder
    {
        get { return entry.Placeholder; }
        set { entry.Placeholder = value; }
    }
}
```

I have tried to use this control in one of my content page is like

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="LearningApp.Views.TriggersDemo.DataTriggers"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:LearningApp.UserControls">
    <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
        <Label FontSize="Large" FontAttributes="Bold" Text="{Binding lblText}"></Label>
        <local:CustomeEntry   Text="{Binding Name}" Command="{Binding CancelCommand}" PlaceHolder="Enter Name"/>
        <Button Command="{Binding CheckCommand}" Text="Check" />

    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

code behind of above mentioned content page is

```
 namespace LearningApp.Views.TriggersDemo
{
    public partial class DataTriggers : ContentPage
    {
        public DataTriggers()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.BindingContext = new TriggersViewModel();

        }

    }
}
```

and My ViewModel contain the one Property like

```
 private string _Name;

        public string Name
        {
            get { return _Name; }
            set { _Name = value; RaisePropertyChanged(); }
        }
```

Can anyone please guide how I can bind the Entry `Text` of UserControl to my ViewModel property `Name` direct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In you `CustomerEntry` there is no control that displays the Text you're binding to.

You have to set up all the bindings in your custom control too.

You can also pass a handler to the `TextProperty`'s [`propertyChanged'](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Xamarin.Forms.BindableProperty.Create/p/System.String/System.Type/System.Type/System.Object/Xamarin.Forms.BindingMode/Xamarin.Forms.BindableProperty+ValidateValueDelegate/Xamarin.Forms.BindableProperty+BindingPropertyChangedDelegate/Xamarin.Forms.BindableProperty+BindingPropertyChangingDelegate/Xamarin.Forms.BindableProperty+CoerceValueDelegate/Xamarin.Forms.BindableProperty+CreateDefaultValueDelegate/) parameter, and set other view's properties on behalf.

Remove the properties from the custom control and bind directly to the `BindingContext` which will be passed along (containing you viewmodel).
Then set `Text="{Binding Text=.}"` in your custom control's entry (same with `Button`'s `Command`) to have it bind to the text from the `BindingContext`, in fact you can remove all your properties from the custom control, and bind directly to the ViewModel.

Comment: Yes, but how I can bind the usercontrol entry from my ContentPage where I have used usercontrol